# Instana Installation inquiry

Tags: instana

I am trying to install Instana on docker, but when configuring the repository for RHEL there is a variable called **DOWNLOAD_KEY=<download_key>**

how can I get that variable "DOWNLOAD_KEY"?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqh4K.png)

```
export DOWNLOAD_KEY=<download_key>

cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/Instana-Product.repo
[instana-product]
name=Instana-Product
baseurl=https://_:$DOWNLOAD_KEY@artifact-public.instana.io/artifactory/rel-rpm-public-virtual/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=https://_:$DOWNLOAD_KEY@artifact-public.instana.io/artifactory/api/security/keypair/public/repositories/rel-rpm-public-virtual
repo_gpgcheck=1
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Your agent key (available from the Instana UI) can be used as a download key.

Comment: I found the download_key after downloading the package from the access catalog of IBM. it is the settings.hcl file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localhost:42699, try to get the IP that assigned to k8s nodes.

kubectl get node -o wide

The provided link for helm procedure no longer accessible. Try to get the latest instruction the latest Instana docu.

Good luck!